# julia installation FUBAR

Tags: installation, julia

I am trying to install a fresh julia on a linux box, and get this. Any suggestions about what to do, and what is causing this?

```
(@v1.7) pkg> add LLVM
   Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package LLVM [929cbde3]:
 LLVM [929cbde3] log:
 ├─possible versions are: 0.9.0-4.9.1 or uninstalled
 ├─restricted to versions 3.9.0 by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 
3.9.0
 └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: 4.0.0-4.9.1 or 
uninstalled — no versions left
```

Comment: You have picked up a very low level package as your first package on Julia... try using Julia 1.6, the one explicitly named in the [LLVM.jl Project.toml file](https://github.com/maleadt/LLVM.jl/blob/master/Project.toml).

Comment: I can install LLVM.jl on Julia 1.7. Try setting JULIA_DEPOT_PATH to some other empty folder and install again.

Comment: I'd say there are other packages conflicting. Which packages do you have, i.e., what is the output of `]status`? Maybe you can try to just update the others first with `]up`. Otherwise you can create a new environment and add all the packages you need until you get an error, so you know which are conflicting.

Comment: @Oskar This was a clean install from 1.7.2 binary. By the way, the 1.9 source build worked fine.

Comment: @IgorRivin Did you try removing and adding again the general registry? I.e.
`pkg> registry rm General` and `pkg> registry add https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General`

Comment: By "clean install from 1.7.2 binary" you mean as downloaded from julialang.org/downloads, right? It sounds like it, but just wanted to explicitly confirm that - LLVM related problems are often because of Julia being installed from the OS package manager.